# String Check operation in MySQL and Mapping it to a different Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table in which i have a time field in INT(10) format. I am storing UnixTime in it. Some of the records have a Zero value and some have a date in it. I want to build a query which shows "No Date" if the value is 0 else show the stored date if there is any date stored in the record on query execution.

The table looks something like this...

ID   DATE

1      0 
2     0506009

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT IF(date=0, 'No Date', date) FROM table;
```

(I'd suggest to store `NULL` instead of `0`.)

Comment: the problem is that the database is too big with thousands of records. Now nothing can be done to replace it with NULL

Comment: @Abhishek: I don't see how a few thousand records has any impact on converting to null: `[UPDATE table SET date = NULL where date = 0;]